# Two seemingly identical unicode strings turn out to be different when using repr(), but how can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have two lists of unicode strings, one containing words picked up from a text file, another containing a list of sound file names from a directory, stripped from their extension. Some of the words in one list are the same as those from the other. I tried to find the matches using `re.search(ur'(?iu)\b%s\b' % string1, string2)`, fnmatch, and even simple `string1 == string2` type comparisons, all of which worked when typing the first list myself for testing, but failed when using the actual list of words retrieved from a text file.

While performing a test to find out why, I monitored the vietnamese word `chào`, present in both lists. Using `isinstance(string, unicode)` confirmed they were both unicode. However, using `repr()` on both strings returned `u'ch\xe0o'` in one case and `u'cha\u0300o'` in the other. So it's pretty clear why they won't match.

So I seem to have found the cause, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried using `.decode('utf-8')` as I thought `\xe0` could be utf-8. But all it did was returning a Unicode encode error. Beside, if both strings are unicode and represent the same word, shouldn't they be the same? Doing `print('%s Vs. %s' % (string1, string2))` returns `chào Vs. chào` I'm kind of lost here.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Unicode characters can be specified different ways, as you've discovered, either as a single codepoint or as a regular codepoint plus a combining codepoint. The character `\u0300` is a [COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm), which adds an accent mark to the preceding character.

The process of fixing a string to a common representation is called *normalization*. You can use [the `unicodedata` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) to do this:

```
def n(str):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', str)

>>> n(u'ch\xe0o') == n(u'cha\u0300o')
True
```

Comment: The other reply was very informative as well but yours also provides actual usable code. I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be in an ambiguous representation of grave accents in unicode. Here is [LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0/index.htm) and here is [COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm) which when combined with 'a' becomes more or less the exact same character as the first. So two representations of the same character. In fact unicode has a term for this: [unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

To implement this in python, use [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) on the string before comparing. I tried 'NFC' mode which returns u'ch\xe0o' for both strings.

Comment: Scratch the "more or less". Any sane Unicode implementation will render the same glyph in both cases.