# python - encoding, print can't figure out

Tags: python, unicode, printing, python-2.x

These two strings look identical when printed but they are not equal under the hood. I need to select a dictionary item by this key but I get keyError because obviously they do not match. I have tried using **str.encode("utf-8")**, **str.decode("utf-8")**, **unicode(str, "utf-8")**, **repr()**. Nothing helped. How can I make them equal just like when they are *print*ed? Thanks.

```
>>> str1 = u"extra\u00f1ar"
>>> str2 = u"extrañar"
>>> str1
u'extra\xf1ar'
>>> str2
u'extran\u0303ar'
>>> print str1
extrañar
>>> print str2
extrañar
>>> str1 == str2
False
```

Comment: They are not printed the same, the `~` is once on the `n` and once on the `a` on the second one. I do not get your problem.

Comment: Also, the ñ it's in utf-8 encoding, so you can use Python 3 (highly recommended) or if you're forced to use Python 2, add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: The ~ is on the n in both strings in the question source code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoPYO.png.  stack overflow just seems to show it wrong ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwSPG.png )

Comment: As correctly noted by @Alex028502 they appear identical when printed. You can try in your console to assure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two seemingly identical unicode strings turn out to be different when using repr(), but how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151641/two-seemingly-identical-unicode-strings-turn-out-to-be-different-when-using-repr)

Comment: funny thing is that they don't like completely identical in my terminal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlKNs.png
but they do once I copy the terminal text into the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `unicodedata.normalize`, but it isn't guaranteed to work:

```
>>> str1 = u'extra\xf1ar'
>>> str2 = u'extran\u0303ar'
>>> str1 == str2
False
>>> print str1; print str2
extrañar
extrañar
```

So, observe:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str1)
u'extra\xf1ar'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str2)
u'extra\xf1ar'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str2) == unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str2)
True
>>> print unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str2); print unicodedata.normalize('NFC', str2)
extrañar
extrañar
```

One [caveat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

> Even if two unicode strings are normalized and look the same to a
>   human reader, if one has combining characters and the other doesn’t,
>   they may not compare equal.